# Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: data not accepted - Outlook Relay Server

Tags: php, email, outlook, phpmailer, exchange-server

My website that was working well over years stopped working yesterday with the following error code. It seems like my mail server and receiving server is communicating, but somehow I am not allowed to release the e-mail that is supposed to be sent:

```
2023-08-16 09:06:27 Connection: opening to relay-hosting.secureserver.net:25, timeout=300, options=array()
2023-08-16 09:06:27 Connection: opened
2023-08-16 09:06:27 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 p3nlsmtp20.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net : HOSTING RELAY : ESMTP Grid hosting relay server ready
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO website.com
2023-08-16 09:06:27 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-p3nlsmtp20.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net hello [50.62.169.106], pleased to meet you250-HELP250-SIZE 50000000250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250 OK
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2023-08-16 09:06:27 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO website.com
2023-08-16 09:06:27 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-p3nlsmtp20.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net hello [50.62.169.106], pleased to meet you250-HELP250-SIZE 50000000250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 OK
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<report@website.com>
2023-08-16 09:06:27 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 <report@website.com> sender ok
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<receiver@receiver.com.tr>
2023-08-16 09:06:27 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 <receiver@receiver.com.tr> recipient ok
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2023-08-16 09:06:27 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 OK
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 16 Aug 2023 12:06:27 +0300
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: receiver@receiver.com.tr
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Website <report@website.com>
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Notification
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <smyl3Vxx5xHKdnoc4tQLzbRXiBMn1WcRwoOWJiylqs@website.com>
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.8.0 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1=_smyl3Vxx5xHKdnoc4tQLzbRXiBMn1WcRwoOWJiylqs"
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1=_smyl3Vxx5xHKdnoc4tQLzbRXiBMn1WcRwoOWJiylqs
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: VG8gdmlldyB0aGUgbWVzc2FnZSwgcGxlYXNlIHVzZSBhbiBIVE1MIGNvbXBhdGlibGUgZW1haWwg
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: dmlld2VyIQ==
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1=_smyl3Vxx5xHKdnoc4tQLzbRXiBMn1WcRwoOWJiylqs
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+PHN0cm9uZz4xLiBBYm91dCB3aGljaCBjb21wYW55IHdvdWxkIHlvdSBsaWtl
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: IHRvIG1ha2UgYSByZXBvcnQ/PC9zdHJvbmc+PGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+Q29tcGFueSBOYW1lOiA8L3N0
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: cm9uZz5hPGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+RGVwYXJ0bWVudCBTZWN0aW9uOiA8L3N0cm9uZz5hPGJyPjxicj48
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: c3Ryb25nPjIuIFdoZXJlIGlzIHRoZSBjb21wYW55IGxvY2F0ZWQ/PC9zdHJvbmc+PGJyPjxzdHJv
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: bmc+QWRkcmVzczogPC9zdHJvbmc+YTxicj48c3Ryb25nPkNpdHk6IDwvc3Ryb25nPmE8YnI+PHN0
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: cm9uZz5Db3VudHJ5OiA8L3N0cm9uZz5hPGJyPjxicj48c3Ryb25nPjMuIFBsZWFzZSBpbmRpY2F0
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: ZSB5b3VyIHJlbGF0aW9uc2hpcCB0byB0aGUgY29tcGFueS48L3N0cm9uZz48YnI+TcO8xZ90ZXJp
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: OiA8YnI+PGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+NC4gV291bGQgeW91IGxpa2UgdG8gcHJvdmlkZSB5b3VyIG5hbWU/
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: PC9zdHJvbmc+PGJyPkhhecSxciwgYW5vbmltIGthbG1hayBpc3RpeW9ydW0uPGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: TmFtZTogPC9zdHJvbmc+PGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+VGVsIE5vOiA8L3N0cm9uZz48YnI+PHN0cm9uZz5F
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: LU1haWw6IDwvc3Ryb25nPjxicj48YnI+PHN0cm9uZz41LiBQbGVhc2UgdGVsbCB1cyB5b3VyIGNv
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: bmNlcm5zIGluIGRldGFpbC48L3N0cm9uZz48YnI+YTxicj48YnI+PHN0cm9uZz42LiBBbW9uZyB3
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: aG9tIHRoaXMgaXNzdWUgaGFzIG9jY3VyZWQgb3IgaXMgb2NjdXJpbmc/PC9zdHJvbmc+PGJyPmE8
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: YnI+PGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+Ny4gV2hlcmUgdGhpcyBpc3N1ZSBoYXMgb2NjdXJlZCBvciBpcyBvY2N1
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: cmluZz88L3N0cm9uZz48YnI+YTxicj48YnI+PHN0cm9uZz44LiBEbyB5b3Uga25vdyB3aGVuIHRo
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: aXMgaXNzdWUgaGFzIG9jY3VyZWQgb3Igc3RhcnRlZCBvY2N1cmluZz8gSWYgaXQgaXMgbm90IG9j
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: Y3VyZWQgeWV0LCB3aGVuIHdpbGwgaXQgb2NjdXI/PC9zdHJvbmc+PGJyPkhhecSxcjxicj48YnI+
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: PGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+OS4gSG93IG1hbnkgdGltZXMgaGFzIGl0IG9jY3VyZWQ/IElzIGl0IHJlY3Vy
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: cmluZz88L3N0cm9uZz48YnI+YTxicj48YnI+PHN0cm9uZz4xMC4gRGlkIHlvdSB3aXRuZXNzIHRo
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: ZSBpc3N1ZSBvciBkaWQgeW91IGhlYXIgaXQgZnJvbSBzb21lb25lIGVsc2U/PC9zdHJvbmc+PGJy
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: Pk9sYXlhIMWfYWhpdCBvbGR1bS48YnI+PGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+V291bGQgeW91IGxpa2UgdG8gc2hh
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: cmUgdGhlIG5hbWVzIG9mIHRoZSBvdGhlciB3aXRuZXNzZXM/PC9zdHJvbmc+PGJyPiA8YnI+IDxi
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: cj48YnI+PHN0cm9uZz4xMS4gV2hlbiBkaWQgeW91IGJlY29tZSBhd2FyZSBvZiB0aGUgaXNzdWU/
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: IFdobyBhcmUgdGhlIHdpdG5lc3NlcyB0byB0aGUgY2FzZSwgaWYgYW55Pzwvc3Ryb25nPjxicj5h
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: PGJyPjxicj48c3Ryb25nPjEyLiBIYXZlIHlvdSBub3RpZmllZCB5b3VyIG1hbmFnZXJzPzwvc3Ry
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: b25nPjxicj5IYXnEsXI8YnI+PGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+V291bGQgeW91IGxpa2UgdG8gc2hhcmUgeW91
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: ciBtYW5hZ2VyJ3MgbmFtZT88L3N0cm9uZz48YnI+PGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+WW91ciBtYW5hZ2VyJ3Mg
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: dGl0bGU6IDwvc3Ryb25nPjxicj48c3Ryb25nPllvdXIgbWFuYWdlcidzIG5hbWUgYW5kIHN1cm5h
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: bWU6IDwvc3Ryb25nPjxicj48YnI+PHN0cm9uZz5IYXMgeW91ciBtYW5hZ2VyIHRha2VuIGFuIGFj
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: dGlvbj88L3N0cm9uZz48YnI+PGJyPjxicj48YnI+PHN0cm9uZz4xMy4gV2hvIGVsc2UgaXMgYXdh
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: cmUgYW5kIGtub3dzIHRoZSBpc3N1ZT88L3N0cm9uZz48YnI+YTxicj48YnI+PHN0cm9uZz4xNC4g
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: SXMgdGhlcmUgYW55IGV2aWRlbmNlL2RvY3VtZW50YXRpb24gcmVsYXRlZCB0byB0aGUgaXNzdWU/
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: IElmIHNvLCBpcyBpdCBwb3NzaWJsZSB0byBzaGFyZSB0aGVtPzwvc3Ryb25nPjxicj5IYXnEsXIs
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: IG1ldmN1dCBkZcSfaWwuPGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+RXhwbGFuYXRpb246PC9zdHJvbmc+PGJyPjxicj48
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: YnI+PHN0cm9uZz4xNS4gSXMgdGhlcmUgYW55IGV2aWRlbmNlL2RvY3VtZW50YXRpb24gdGhhdCB5
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: b3UgZG8gbm90IGRpcmVjdGx5IGhvbGQgYnV0IGl0IGlzIHRob3VnaHQva25vd24gdG8gYmUgcG9z
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: c2Vzc2VkIGJ5IHNvbWVvbmUgZWxzZT8gSWYgZXhpc3RzLCBpcyB0aGVyZSBhbnkgd2F5IHRvIGFj
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: Y2VzcyB0aGVtPzwvc3Ryb25nPjxicj5IYXnEsXIsIG1ldmN1dCBkZcSfaWwuPGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: RXhwbGFuYXRpb246PC9zdHJvbmc+PGJyPjxicj48YnI+PHN0cm9uZz4xNi4gSXMgdGhlcmUgYW55
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: dGhpbmcgZWxzZSB5b3Ugd291bGQgbGlrZSB0byBhZGQ/PC9zdHJvbmc+PGJyPkhhecSxcjxicj48
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: YnI+PGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+MTcuIEhvdyBkaWQgeW91IGJlY29tZSBhd2FyZSBvZiB0aGUgRXRoaWNz
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: IEhvdGxpbmU/PC9zdHJvbmc+PGJyPkXEn2l0aW08YnI+PGJyPjxicj48L2JvZHk+PC9odG1sPg==
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1=_smyl3Vxx5xHKdnoc4tQLzbRXiBMn1WcRwoOWJiylqs--
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2023-08-16 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2023-08-16 09:06:46 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2023-08-16 09:06:46 SMTP ERROR: DATA END command failed:
SMTP Error: data not accepted.

Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: data not accepted. in G:\PleskVhostswebsite.com\PHPMailer_master\src\PHPMailer.php:2051 Stack trace: #0 G:\PleskVhostswebsite.com\PHPMailer_master\src\PHPMailer.php(1678): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend() #1 G:\PleskVhosts\website.com\PHPMailer_master\src\PHPMailer.php(1516): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend() #2 G:\PleskVhosts\website.com\formSubmitFinal.php(239): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() #3 {main} thrown in G:\PleskVhosts\website.com\PHPMailer_master\src\PHPMailer.php on line 2051
2023-08-16 09:06:46 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
2023-08-16 09:06:46 Connection: closed
```

My php configuration is set as follows (Notice that I have been using relay server for sending automatic e-mails):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->setLanguage('en', 'G:\path\path\path');
$mail->CharSet='utf-8';
$mail->Encoding='base64';

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net ';
        
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';
$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->From = ('report@website.com');
$mail->addAddress('receiver@receiver.com.tr');
$mail->FromName = 'Website';
```

Here is my Godaddy error log trace:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: data not accepted. in G:\PleskVhosts\website.com\path\PHPMailer_master\src\PHPMailer.php:2051
Stack trace:
#0 G:\PleskVhosts\website.com\path\PHPMailer_master\src\PHPMailer.php(1678): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend()
#1 G:PleskVhosts\website.com\path\PHPMailer_master\src\PHPMailer.php(1516): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend()
#2 G:PleskVhosts\website.com\path\PHPMailer_master\src\formSubmitFinal.php(239): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send()
#3 {main}
thrown in G:\PleskVhosts\website.com\path\PHPMailer_master\src\PHPMailer.php on line 2051
```

The line 2051 is as follows inside the PHPMailer.php

```
 //Only send the DATA command if we have viable recipients
        if ((count($this->all_recipients) > count($bad_rcpt)) && !$this->smtp->data($header . $body)) {
            throw new Exception($this->lang('data_not_accepted'), self::STOP_CRITICAL);
        }
```

I know there are similar questions on stackoverflow but I could not find any related to Exchange server or with same error code. Again I have not changed any code inside my web page but since yesterday, I was getting that error.

The methods I have tried to solve this problem is as follows:

- Updating php version to the latest
- Trying multiple different SMTP connections such as following:

  Server name: smtp.office365.com
  Port: 587
  Encryption method: STARTTLS
- Contacting with GoDaddy over any possible hosting - domain property
  changes
- Checking outlook settings
- Disabling previous phpmailer code given above

I have been dealing with this error for a while. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: GoDaddy is difficult to send from, and you definitely can’t send from outlook domains on there. I’d recommend checking your SPF setup, and contacting GoDaddy support. You could try sending through localhost, as per the example config in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide.

Comment: Yeah but GoDaddy just passed to outlook from Google workspace about a year ago. It was a misery since then. I talked to GoDaddy, sad thing is they I asked me to tell them the solution if I ever figure out. I will call GoDaddy USA today also probably will send an e-mail to Microsoft.